# Rails 3 app broken, if access from Internet Explorer 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, prototype, internet-explorer-9

I have a Rails 3 application hosted on Heroku.  One controller serves JS rendered from a .js.haml file:

```
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/u/verses/13" for 217.28.52.97 at 2011-    10-11 07:03:36 -0700
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by VersesController#show as JS
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"author"=>"u", "id"=>"13"}
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered verses/show.js.haml (1.7ms)
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 2.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.kuular.ru/u/verses/13 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=854
2011-10-11T14:03:36+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 217.28.52.97 - - [11/Oct/2011:07:03:36 -0700] "GET /u/verses/13 HTTP/1.1" 200 854 "http://www.kuular.ru/u/verses" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.904.0 Safari/535.7" www.kuular.ru
```

This log is produced when accessed from *any* JS-enabled browser, except MSIE 9, which, in turn, triggers an error:

```
011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/u/verses/123" for 217.28.52.97 at 2011-10-11 07:07:19 -0700
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by VersesController#show as JS
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"author"=>"u", "id"=>"123"}
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered verses/show.js.haml (3.2ms)
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/u/verses/123" for 217.28.52.97 at 2011-10-11 07:07:19 -0700
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by VersesController#show as HTML
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"author"=>"u", "id"=>"123"}
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.kuular.ru/u/verses/123 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=975
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 217.28.52.97 - - [11/Oct/2011:07:07:19 -0700] "GET /u/verses/123 HTTP/1.1" 200 975 "http://www.kuular.ru/u/verses" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" www.kuular.ru
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template verses/show with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/app/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/simple_http_auth/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_serve_static_assets/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/rails3_disable_x_sendfile/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/picasa_on_rails/app/views", "/app/vendor/plugins/haml/app/views"):
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_view/paths.rb:15:in `find'
2011-10-11T14:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.10/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:81:in `find'
```

I noticed that the request is sent twice, but why, and why is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Prototype 1.7 RC3 cured the problem.